# Memory Leak when SQLite and MySQL ODBC Connectors on same machine

Tags: mysql, sqlite, odbc

This is the most frustrating bug I have ever seen. I have the latest GA version of SQLLite and MySQL ODBC connectors, vb.net, vs2010. I have two programs, one that acts as a server and accesses an SQLLite database, and a client that queries the server program and compares the result with a MySQL database. The client-server exchange is with serialized XML over TCP, so its not affecting things.

With the server program running, I can run MySQL queries all day long and memory usage of the client program doesn't change. However, as soon as I run a command to the server, the server access the SQLite database and returns an answer, from that point forward EVERY MySQL query that the client does results in a 60-100K increase in memory usage by the client program, until memory fills up and the MySQL client fails with an Out of Memory or Connection is Closed message.

I've tried have to have the server explicitly close the SQLite connection after every query, I've tried having the client software close the MySQL connection after every query, and there is no change. I tried releasing the object pool on ODBCConnection, calling dispose explicitly, everything I could think of to force the client to free up the memory used by the MySQL ODBC Connector, but nothing works. The only thing I can think of is that maybe the SQLite and MySQL Connector don't play well together? Help!

Comment: This is a good question, but please go back to some of your previous questions and accept an answer. This will encourage others to answer this question.

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't realize that was a step I had to take to close a question.

Comment: There is definetly a conflict of some kind. I re-wrote all the code in the server so that it used a MySQL database and I was still getting the same behavior. It wasn't until I removed the reference to System.Data.Sqlite itself that it stopped.